# System-install-packages missing in RedHat Enterprise Linux 5

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5, package-management

i am using RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.1. When i use add-remove software in application menu, i think, that i wrongly uninstalled something. so after reboot that menu item missing.

Also i can't use system-install-packages in terminal.

When i double click rpm package it open as archive.

And i specifically open  it as software installer by open with other application, it saying error `/usr/bin/system-install-packages missing`.

Help me to solve this problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### have rpm tell you what package provides that file

1. which system-install-packages
   /usr/bin/system-install-packages
2. rpm -qif /usr/bin/system-install-packages

Name        : pirut                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.3.28                            Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
Release     : 13.el5                        Build Date: Wed 19 Mar 2008 03:08:18 PM MDT
Install Date: Mon 07 Dec 2009 02:39:48 PM MST      Build Host: js20-bc1-9.build.redhat.com
Group       : Applications/System           Source RPM: pirut-1.3.28-13.el5.src.rpm
Size        : 1477554                          License: GPL
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Fri 25 Apr 2008 11:53:09 AM MDT, Key ID 5326810137017186

Summary     : Package Installation, Removal and Update Tools
Description :
pirut (pronounced "pirate") provides a set of graphical tools for managing
software.

3. yum upgrade pirut or yum install pirut
4. try it again.

Answer (score 2):

**rpm -qa** will tell you what packages are there, and by inference, what is missing.

```
rpm -qf  /usr/bin/system-install-packages
```

tells me that this file is in the pirut package, such as pirut-1.3.28-13.el5.rpm.

You can find the RPM files on your install disks, or use yum. If you have the RPM file, use the **rpm -i *packagename.rpm*** command to install them.